# printing memory as 1 byte hex in C

Tags: memory, printing, hex

Could you please help me with the following C problem? I am trying to print a list of 30 successive values, starting at a certain memory address. I would like to print 1 byte as a hex per memory location. As an indication of which memory address to insert, I am printing the address of a dummy at the start of the program.

The problem is that I get values of more than 1 byte. For long sequences of zeros this still results in 00, but as soon as non-zero values show up, I get a print of a 4 byte 'window'. This results in the following output:

```
Main function address is 0x8048494 
Dummy variable address is 0x9a2e008 
Enter the address (without the 0x):9a2e008
You entered: 9a2e008 
Address     Byte value 
0x9a2e008   00 
0x9a2e009   00 
0x9a2e00a   00 
0x9a2e00b   00 
0x9a2e00c   00 
0x9a2e00d   00 
0x9a2e00e   00 
0x9a2e00f   00 
0x9a2e010   00 
0x9a2e011   f1000000 
0x9a2e012   ff10000     
0x9a2e013   20ff100 
0x9a2e014   20ff1 
0x9a2e015   3900020f 
0x9a2e016   61390002 
0x9a2e017   32613900 
0x9a2e018   65326139 
0x9a2e019   30653261 
0x9a2e01a   30306532 
0x9a2e01b   38303065 
0x9a2e01c   383030 
0x9a2e01d   3830 
0x9a2e01e   38 
0x9a2e01f   00 
0x9a2e020   00 
0x9a2e021   00 
0x9a2e022   00 
0x9a2e023   00 
0x9a2e024   00 
0x9a2e025   00
```

My code so far is:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NUMBER_OF_BYTES 10

void showAddresses(void);
void printMemoryAtAddress(void);

int * dummy;                                    
int dumpSize = 30;                                          

int main(void)
{
    dummy = (int *) malloc     (sizeof(int));                                       showAddresses();                                        
    printMemoryAtAddress();
    return 0;
}

void showAddresses(void)
{
    printf("Main function address is %p \n", main);
    printf("Dummy variable address is %p \n",(void*)dummy);
}

void printMemoryAtAddress(void)
{
    int input;
    printf("Enter the address (without the 0x):");
    scanf("%x", &input);
    printf("You entered: %x \n", input);
    printf("Address \tByte value \n");

    int i;
    for(i=0;i<dumpSize;i++)
    {
        int* address;
        address = (int*) (input+i);
        printf("%p \t", address);   
        printf("%.2x \n", *address);                                        
    }
}
```

Any help with this problem would be very much appreciated! If this question is stupid, I apologize. (I am still learning and can't seem to find a solution after hours of trying!)
Joe

Comment: Change `int* address;` to `unsigned char *address;`

Comment: thank you for your fast reply! that worked! Nice nickname by the way :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
void printMemoryAtAddress(void)
{
    int input;
    printf("Enter the address (without the 0x):");
    scanf("%x", &input);
    printf("You entered: %x \n", input);
    printf("Address \tByte value \n");

    int i;
    for(i=0;i<dumpSize;i++)
    {
        int* address;
        address = (int*) (input+i);
        printf("%p \t", address);   
        printf("%.2x \n", *address);                                        
    }
}
```

**address** should be an unsigned char* not an int*. As an int* it reads the memory as if it were an integer, you want it to be read as a char which is only one byte.

Good luck!

Comment: Wow that was fast! Thank you for your help, it did the trick!